# Avoid processing duplicate data when CSV importing via Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of CSV files with duplicate data, i.e. the same row might (and does) appear in multiple files. Each row is uniquely identified by one of the columns (id) and has quite a few other columns that indicate properties, as well as required relationships (i.e. ids of other nodes to link to). The files all have the same format.

My problem is that, due to size and number of the files, I want to avoid processing the rows that already exist - I know that as long as id is the same, the contents of the rows will be the same across the files.

Can any cypher wizard advise how to write a query that would create the node, set all the properties and create all the relationship if a node with given id does not exist, but skip the action altogether if such node is found? I tried with MERGE ON CREATE, something along the lines of:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "..." AS row
MERGE (f:MyLabel {id:row.uniqueId})
ON CREATE SET f....
WITH f,row
MATCH (otherNode:OtherLabel {id : row.otherNodeId})
MERGE (f) -[:REL1] -> (otherNode)
```

but unfortunately that can only be applied to not setting the properties again, but I couldn't work out how to skip the merging part of relationships (only shown one here, but there are quite a few more).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why skip the merging of the relationships?  If you're merging them, then they shouldn't get re-created.  Also have you checked that the `MERGE` statement has an `ON CREATE` but also has an `ON MATCH` where you can specify that it does something different if a node already existed?

Comment: Yup, @FrobberOfBits is right. if your query works fine during creation and all you want is to not `MERGE` when an instance already exists. Right after what you have, use `ON MATCH SET` and then write the custom query.

Comment: What I mean is I don't want to perform the matching/merging of the relationships as it's a waste of time - as said, the dataset is large, once I match that node by id I want to skip any further processing - ON CREATE/ON MATCH only works for the SET operation as far as I know - it doesn't allow to skip the MERGE relationships bit. I know the relationships wouldn't be duplicated, but matching them (it's quite a few more than shown here) is simply unnecessary and makes the import slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just optionally match the node and then skip with `WHERE n IS NULL`
Make sure you have an index or constraint on `:MyLabel(id)`

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "..." AS row
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:MyLabel {id:row.uniqueId})
WHERE f IS NULL
MERGE (f:MyLabel {id:row.uniqueId})
ON CREATE SET f....
WITH f,row
MATCH (otherNode:OtherLabel {id : row.otherNodeId})
MERGE (f) -[:REL1] -> (otherNode)
```

Comment: Sweet, that's exactly what I was after. I had to change the name of the identifier (can't use f twice) but seems to work like charm :) Thank you! I must have had a temporary brain failure not being able to figure this out myself :)